# The Invisibility of the NULL value that is returned by a loop

Tags: r, loops, null

According to the R Language Definition (version 3.0.2),

> The value returned by a loop statement statement is always NULL and is returned invisibly.

([sec. 3.2.2 "Looping"](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Looping))

What does it mean for a value to be returned *invisibly*?

Comment: @SeñorO the question is not really asking what the function `invisible` does (though the question is inextricably linked to that function). I don't think it falls under *exact duplicate* (though I could be misinterpreting).

Comment: @SimonO101 I think you're right - but I think the **answer** to this question will inevitably be an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All functions must return something. `invisible` means the return value isn't visible to the user. Consider the simple function below:

```
f <- function(){
    x <- 2
    return( x )
}

#  Returns 2..
> f()
[1] 2

#  Returns 2 but you can't see it
f <- function(){
    x <- 2
    return( invisible(x) )
}

> f()
> 
#  But it is still returned...

str(f())
#num 2
```

You can see the return value of a `for` loop like so for example...

```
str( for( i in 1:3 ){} )
# NULL
```

Even `invisible` itself must return something...

```
str( invisible() )
# NULL
```